# Getting the history of an object

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I use django admin for my users to add their Model objects, as you know django is keeping the track of user actions such as the user who added an item. For an object, At a custom view outside the admin panel, I need to display the user name of the adder.

How can I fetch/retrieve this data ?

Cheers

Comment: I made an important edit that makes sure the id matches the id of that specific model (because different models can contain objects with the same id).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a rough sketch but should be pretty close to what you need for your view:

```
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry, ADDITION

def your_view(request):
    ...
    # This is your object that was modified
    my_obj = ...
    log_entry = LogEntry.objects.filter(
        object_id=my_obj.id,
        action_flag=ADDITION,
        content_type__id__exact=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(MyModel).id)
    ...
```

Then in your template:

```
{{ log_entry.user.username }}
```

Comment: this looks promising, as my item can have several actions, how can I retrieve the "add" action, I have been checking the database structure of  "django_admin_log", seems like the "action_flag" keeps the action.

Comment: from django.contrib.admin.models import ADDITION

filter(..., action_flag=ADDITION)

Comment: Edited answer to include ADDITION filter

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to add additional functionality beyond what was mentioned above, I've made use of an app called [django-reversion](http://code.google.com/p/django-reversion/) which in addition to making the log accessible would also provide a copy of what was changed (that incidentally can also be used to generate a DIFF with or without HTML showing the changes).